# Renewing US visa via mail still possible?

Tags: usa, j-visa, german-citizens

I am currently holding a J-1 visa, which I have to renew very soon in my home country (Germany). Previously, I was able to renew this visa via mail where I just mailed all my documents to the consulate, they processed it and sent the documents including my passport with a new visa back to me.

Is this still possible under the new executive order, or do I have to appear in person at the consulate now?

Comment: I do not know the answer to your question, but I do want to ask whether you realize that renewing the visa is only necessary if you want to leave the US and then return in J-1 status; a valid visa is not a requirement to remain in the US.

Comment: Yes, I know that but I want to visit my home country. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: I did exactly that in December, things were still the same. I mailed in all my documents and got them back within 10 days. I am not sure it has changed, but never know these days.

Answer (score 1):

First, the executive order is not currently in force because a court has temporarily enjoined the administration from enforcing it.  The temporary restraining order could be lifted in the future, so the executive order might come into force again.

Under the executive order, there is no change to visa procedures for those who aren't affected by it (that is, for those who are not refugees and are not "from" one of the affected countries; the lack of precision in this statement is because the interpretation of the order has been changing).

However, this could change.  The order mandates a review of visa procedures, and it is possible that renewal by mail could be eliminated or curtailed in the future as a result of the review.

Your best bet, therefore, is to get in touch with the consulate and ask them.  If you do, please come back and post an answer to the question.